# radio button change visible input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

### I'm trying to do a separate formulary for individuals and corporations

#### If the visitor check the "Individual" radio button, it would display a form

#### If the visitor check the "Corporation" radio button, it would display a different form

```
 <fieldset>
                    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cadastro" value="individual_form" id="individual_form" style="margin:0px !important">
                    <strong>Individual Form</strong><br/>

                    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cadastro" value="corporation_form" id="corporation_form" style="margin:0px !important">
                    <strong>Corporation Form</strong>

            <!-- If Individual Form is checked -->
            <legend>Personal Data</legend>
            <label for="Name">Full Name</label>
            <input id="Name" type="text" />
            <label for="City">City</label>
            <input id="City" type="text" />
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input id="Email" type="text" />

            <!-- If Corporation Form is checked -->
            <legend>Corporation Data</legend>
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input id="Name" type="text" />
            <label for="City">City</label>
            <input id="City" type="text" />
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input id="Email" type="text" />

        </fieldset>
```

Ps: Because of my other javascript, I can't use other `<fieldset>` than the existing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to wrap something around the fields to show/hide, even just a `<div>` tag with an ID.

Then for your radio buttons, you'd want to add `onchange` & `onmouseup` event handlers (to account for people either clicking to change the value, or using their keyboard).
eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onchange_handler(obj, id) {
    var other_id = (id == 'personal')? 'corporate' : 'personal';
    if(obj.checked) {
        document.getElementById(id + '_form_fields').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(other_id + '_form_fields').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id + '_form_fields').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(other_id + '_form_fields').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cadastro" value="individual_form" id="individual_form" style="margin:0px !important" onchange="onchange_handler(this, 'personal');" onmouseup="onchange_handler(this, 'personal');">
    <strong>Individual Form</strong><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="tipo_cadastro" value="corporation_form" id="corporation_form" style="margin:0px !important" onchange="onchange_handler(this, 'corporate');" onmouseup="onchange_handler(this, 'corporate');">
    <strong>Corporation Form</strong>

    <!-- If Individual Form is checked -->
    <div id="personal_form_fields">
        <legend>Personal Data</legend>
        <label for="Name">Full Name</label>
        <input id="Name" type="text" />
        <label for="City">City</label>
        <input id="City" type="text" />
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="Email" type="text" />
    </div>

    <!-- If Corporation Form is checked -->
    <div id="corporate_form_fields" style="display: none;">
        <legend>Corporation Data</legend>
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input id="Name" type="text" />
        <label for="City">City</label>
        <input id="City" type="text" />
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="Email" type="text" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: For what I saw, it changes display:none to block, but not reverse

Comment: Not sure if you saw the fuller example I put in there? I moved it into a javascript function to both show the relevant fields & hide the irrelevant ones (the first bit of code only did the showing). Glad you got it working.